# wait-task not working in powershell

Tags: powershell, powercli

```
Connect-VIServer $vmserver -User $vmuser -Password $vmpass
#Create snapshot
$task1 = New-Snapshot -Name 'variable' -VM $vmname -RunAsync
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
Wait-Task -Task $task1

#Restart VM
$task2 = Restart-VM -VM $vmname -Confirm:$false -RunAsync
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
Wait-Task -Task $task2

#Revert Snapshot
$task3 = Set-VM -VM $vmname  -Snapshot 'Fresh' -Confirm:$false -RunAsync
Wait-Task -Task $task3
```

This is not waiting for the snapshot to be created(`task1`) and proceeds to `task2`, which of course fails since already some operation is being performed .Also, while creating the snapshot it says this operation can't be performed in the current state even though it creates the VM.

Comment: anybody there,please help me out ASAP...i am stuck at this thing for long time today...Thanks,in advance..:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious if `-RunAsync` and `wait-task` can do the job you expect. [Maybe](http://www.lucd.info/2010/02/21/about-async-tasks-the-get-task-cmdlet-and-a-hash-table/) [not](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2008/08/18/powershell-script-to-take-snapshot-on-multiple-vm-machines.aspx)? Check out `help About_RunAsync` if you haven't already.

Here is another approach:

```
New-Snapshot -Name test -VM $vmname
do {write-host "snapping..."; start-sleep -sec 5}
until (get-snapshot -vm $vmname -name test)
write-host "snapped"
```

and another thrilling read: `help wait-job`